# Suppress labeling of features smaller than not working properly

Tags: qgis, labeling

In QGIS there is the option to not label features shorter than a certain value:

("Suppress labeling of features smaller than")

The max. value I can set for the length is 99,99mm. So if I want to supress labeling of features smaller than 0.5m I cannot choose 0,5m as value.

[image]

As a workaround I use this expression which works fine:

```
case when $length>0.49
then MyTextColumn
END
```

Is it possible that the value I can set for this option means length(on my screen or on my sheet of paper) at a certain scale? This would be very misleading as I think for a scale on a screen I would expect to set a value in Pixel.

Comment: Are you using QGIS 2.14? In 2.18 the option is called "pixel size-based visibility" and it's measured in pixels. There are other improvements to labeling and styling that make it quite worthwhile to update.

Comment: no, I am using QGIS 2.18

Comment: That's strange. Must be a difference between the English and German language versions.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is correct, the label `rendering / feature options / suppress small labels` considers the rendered (i.e. on screen) size. There is a direct relationship between pixels and millimeters, so using either one should have consistent outcome.

For you case, the proper way would be to do a `rule based labeling`, with a filter on larger features.

[image]

[image]